# How to solve OSError: decoder jpeg not available on centos 7

Tags: django, centos, python-imaging-library

I'm facing OSError on centos 7.

```
OSError: decoder jpeg not available
```

I tried many solutions for this but still facing same. How to solve this?

Comment: @User, need more details as to when the error happens and how did you install PIL?

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this problem with Python/Django in Ubuntu amazon server.
The solution was to recompile Pillow library after installing the following packagers:

`libjpeg libjpeg-dev libfreetype6 libfreetype6-dev zlib1g-dev`

Probably the package names are different in CentOS, but you can search in yum to get the right names.

That's important to notice that you must uninstall and reinstall Pillow, PIL or any library that depends on these packages.

Answer (score 3):

Rômulo is correct; on CentOS 7, you're going to want to install a few pre-requisites. I also recommend installing EPEL (correct at time of writing):

```
# EPEL
echo 'Enabling Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL) repository...'
yum install http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-7-11.noarch.rpm
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

# Install additional packages
yum install zlib-devel libjpeg-turbo-devel libpng giflib
```

Then give it a try again.